# Softlayer API for filtering Redundant Power Supply

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For package id 271 if I select this package then it gives me only one option for Redundant power supply as:

1)Redundant Power Supply [$7.25]

And if i select package id as 1051 then it gives me two options for Redundant Power Supply as

1)None-No power Supply Required
2)Redundant Power Supply [$7.25]

I want API to filter on packages that when to show 2 options and when to show only one option for Redundant power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if power supply is required through the package [configuration](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package/#configuration), the portal page shows two options when it isn't required.

The following call could help you to retrieve those packages which requires a power supply

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects?objectFilter={"configuration":{"itemCategoryId":{"operation":35},"isRequired":{"operation":1}}}&objectMask=mask[id,configuration]`

And this call list all packages in which it isn't required:

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects?objectFilter={"configuration":{"itemCategoryId":{"operation":35},"isRequired":{"operation":0}}}&objectMask=mask[id,configuration]`